# How to deduce the PDNF of ~A?

Tags: logic, conjunctive-normal-form, disjunctive-normal-form

For my question, $A =\lnot P\land(Q \to R)$. After making the truth table, I managed to get the PDNF of it which is

$$(\lnot p\land q\land r)\lor(\lnot p\land\lnot q\land r)\lor(\lnot p\land\lnot q\land\lnot r).$$

The next part of the question require me to deduce the PDNF of $\lnot A$. Please guide me on how to solve it as most of the other resources I found online are paid-to-use homework websites. Million thanks.

Comment: Use the same method.  In fact, use the same table.  $\neg A$ is true when $A$ is false.

Comment: @GrahamKemp ohhh so deduce the PDNF of ~A simply means to find the PDNF of ~A? Guess the question confused me.